# Cannot run Arquillian Tests for Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven, jboss-arquillian

I'm trying to run Arquillian test for GAE container, however I am getting this error:

```
com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineConfigException: Could not locate /tmp/servlet-test.war/WEB-INF/appengine-web.xml   
at com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:140)com.google.apphosting.utils.config.AppEngineWebXmlReader.getInputStream(AppEngineWebXmlReader.java:140)
```

All my other non-Arquillian tests works fine, not sure why this happens, should I put `appengine-web.xml`   into the test folder? Or having it in the `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` should be fine?

Also in the Maven surefire report I can see this:

```
com.mycompany.AnnotatedEchoServletTestCase  Time elapsed: 1.131 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServer.start()Ljava/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch;
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.appengine.embedded.AppEngineEmbeddedContainer.doDeploy(AppEngineEmbeddedContainer.java:74)
```

I'm just running this [AnnotatedEchoServletTestCase](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-showcase/blob/master/servlet/src/test/java/com/acme/servlet/AnnotatedEchoServletTestCase.java) with GAE container.

My app have this dependency in the app:

```
    <!-- Added for GAE Arquillian Testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxrs-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
         </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency> 
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>${version.arquillian}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>${version.slf4j}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.descriptors</groupId>
        <artifactId>shrinkwrap-descriptors-impl-javaee</artifactId>
    </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
       <artifactId>arquillian-gae-embedded</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0.Beta7</version>
   </dependency>
   <!-- End GAE Arquillian Testing -->
```

What could be missing in my configuration?

Comment: It costs almost nothing to just try what you are asking.

Comment: @MartinBerends Try? I've been trying to make it work, what do you mean. BTW, Martin, I don't see any 'arquillian' tags in your profile :-/

Comment: Sorry @xybrek, have you tried putting appengine-web.xml into the test folder as you asked?  Please add to the question what happened when you did.  And what happened when you had appengine-web.xml in the /src/main/webapp/WEB-INF as you asked?  Please try that and add the results to the information in the question.  No, I don't care to have an Arquillian tag in my profile, so I'd better shut up.

Comment: yup, indeed i did that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22247618/errors-in-running-servlet-test-with-gae-arquillian

Comment: okay, I hope someone figures it out